# How can I make this php redirect not be conflicted by Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, redirect

My php file `404.php` contains a `php` redirect at the top of the file:

```
<?php
    header('Location: some-page.html');
```

If I go to www.mysite.com/404, it redirects to www.mysite.com/some-page.html as expected, however, if I go to www.mysite.com/non-existent-page, the redirect does not work.

In my `nginx.conf`:

```
location ~* \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

error_page 404 =200 /404.php;

try_files $uri @remExt;
location @remExt {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}
if ($request_uri ~ ^/([^?]*)\.php($|\?)) {
    return 301 /$1$is_args$args;
}
rewrite ^/index$ / permanent;
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```

How can I make the php redirect work when visiting www.mysite.com/non-existent-page?

**PS**

Sorry for the badly written question title. The clear and better written question title I wanted to use was automatically rejected.

Comment: When 404 occured, you want to display 404.php, so what you need is the `try_files $uri /404.php` (if $uri is not existed, redirect to 404.php).

Comment: I want it to load 404.php without changing the url. It should also throw 200 because data to generate a page may be stored in the database. If that does not exist, then a 404 page is generated and I throw a 404 error with php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I have solved the problem, although there may be some edge cases where my Nginx code fails.

The problem was with this line `error_page 404 =200 /404.php;`. The solution is to use `try_files` inside `location ~* \.php$`.

```
index index.php;

location ~* \.php$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /404.php$is_args$args;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm-root.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php$is_args$query_string;
}

if ($request_uri ~ ^/([^?]*)\.php($|\?)) {
    return 301 /$1$is_args$args;
}
rewrite ^/index$ / permanent;
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your nginx config and restart it.

```
error_page 404 /404.php;
location = /404.php {
    root /path/to/www/;
    internal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`/404.php`

```
<?php
    http_response_code(301);
    header('Location: /the/page/you/want');
```

`nginx.conf`

```
error_page 404 /404.php
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.php $uri/ =404;
}
```

then check syntax with `nginx -t` and reload nginx with `systemctl reload nginx`(if you're using systemd)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php